# Audio card is not working using Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound

as I say my audio card isn0t working. I've tried to remove and then reinstall the driver but the problem persist. I'm using ASUS F550L.
[Here](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=d8283556b268cb121b6be19297d61c87df59ea32) it's possible see alsa-inf.sh log. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From your alsa-info, various faders from your internal soundcard are muted. The problem is the standard volume controls the default sound card which is the HDMI  on your pc, not the internal soundcard. Try this:

- Install and run pavucontrol (Pulseaudio volume control), go in "output device" tab, scroll down to main soundcard , set its volume and check "mute" state . Also click the green button near it to make it default.
- If no luck, try to launch Alsamixer in a terminal, press F6, select 2nd sound card and increase all volumes (with arrow keys) and check mute state (press "m" to mute/unmute).